# AlertController Swift 3. como puedo obtener activo mi botón de localización mandando una alerta cada que se presione sin ser activado la localización

Tags: ios, swift3

```
 // MARK: - Delegate methods defined by CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        // If status has not yet been determined, ask for authorization
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        // If authorized when in use
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        // If always authorized
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .restricted:
        // If restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
        break
    case .denied:
        // If user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app

        // Disable location icon
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = false

        // Show a pop up
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Access Requested", message: "The location permission was not authorized. Please enable it in Settings to continue.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (alertAction) in
            if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings as URL)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una descripción, además del título, para explicar qué estás queriendo hacer, en qué está fallando y cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: hola! quiero que el botón de localización me mande una alerta cuando no se le dan permisos de localización y al momento de presionar el botón de localización mande la alerta de los permisos....    y cada que presione el botón sin permisos me mande una alerta de recordatorio que los prenda

Answer (score 0):

Esto tiene tiempo y no sé si habrás encontrado ya una solución.

Deberías quitar el popUp de la función didChangeAuthorization porque si el usuario niega los permisos siempre puedes provocar un bucle, y ponerlo solo en la acción del botón. De esta forma cada vez que el usuario pulse el botón de localización y no haya aceptado los permisos, se los volverá a pedir.

```
@IBAction func pulsoBotonLocalizacion(_ sender: AnyObject){

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {

        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Location Access Requested", message: "The location permission was not authorized. Please enable it in Settings to continue.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let alertCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let alertOKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: { Void in
                UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
             })
            alertVC.addAction(alertOKAction)
            alertVC.addAction(alertCancelAction)

            self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
    } else {
        print("Location services are not enabled")
    }
}
```